# Data at the root level is invalid - XML parsing

Tags: c#, xml

I am very new to programming and not sure where I am going wrong. I have read the other threads with similar error, but I think my problem is even basic.

I get a string generated which contains XML, but it doesnt start with an XML. When I try to parse that string I get the above error.

Is there a way of getting rid of the text and save the text from where the XML starts?

My string:

```
{"Id":"6a76f781-f592-4320-a116-6ab289505423","Name":"Test - A","AttachmentRequired":false,"FormXml":"
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>
```

Comment: The outer string is actually [tag:json].  You could use a JSON parser such as [tag:json.net] to pick out the XML.  And in fact the XML has been (correctly) escaped when included in the JSON so that would be the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a JSON parser like Newtonsoft:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Id;
    public string Name;
    public bool AttachmentRequired;
    public string FormXml;

}

var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);


var xml = o.FormXml;
```

Here is the Nuget package to Newtonsoft which I demonstrated above:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

If you absolutely can't use an external library to transform it into a CLR object, here is how you would do it through string manipulation:

```
var str = @"{ ""Id"":""6a76f781-f592-4320-a116-6ab289505423"",""Name"":""Test - A"",""AttachmentRequired"":false,""FormXml"":""<?xml version=\""1.0\"" encoding=\""utf-16\""?>""}";

var parts = str.Split(':');

var last = parts[parts.Length -1];

var xml = last.Replace("}","").Replace("\"<","<").Replace(">\"",">");
```

Answer (score 0):

your string appears to be in json format and xml part of it is a field value for "formxml". [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/xzjNWw8o)

Easy way is to deserialize the string into object using newtonsoft json, and then parse the value of formxml to your object.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(yourstring);
```